# Why does this menu navigation <div> not centre align?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a website with a drop down navigation bar at the top, I would like to centre the navigation bar, but I can't get it to work, it seems to be stuck to the left side. You can view the website [here](http://inmyownview.com/) and I've pasted the code below.

I've been trying to get this to work all day, but I can't see where the problem is. I don't know what more to write, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My style.css:**

```
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding:0;
    margin: auto;
}
#menu ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inherit;
}
#menu li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu li a{
    width:100px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #7B99FF;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
#menu li .subnav a {
    color: #7B99FF;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#menu li .subnav a:hover{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#menu ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
.subnav {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

**My index.php:**

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">About me</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Categories</a>
<ul class="subnav">
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Archive</a>
<ul class="subnav">
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'absolute' position of #menu and give it some width:

```
#menu{
width:400px;
z-index: 1;
padding:0;
margin: auto;}
```

If you don't want to set width manually you can wrap your root  in a div with style:

```
text-align:center
```